# Is something special about the shape of an earthen pot which helps it to cool water?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there a possiblity that by changing the shape of an earthern pot, we can make it cools as well or better?

Answer (score 3):

Earthen pots cool by water diffusing through pores in the material, evaporating on the outside. This suggests that to a first approximation it would cool better if it had greater surface area: a spherical pot would be the worst, while one with fractal branches would be more efficient (but impractical). Also, a too branched pot would likely restrict convection of moist air.

I suspect there is no strict optimum since the actual design would be a trade-off between volume (otherwise a totally flat pot that briefly evaporates a thin film wins), convection ability, and surface area.

Comment: You have to add stability of a filled pot to the list . We have a proverb in modern greek : "how many times will the jug go to the spring of water?"  :)